# Can I use a neural network for regression when input has multiple output values?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, regression, predict

I am trying to use neural networks for a non-linear regression problem for my x,y graph, but in my data some x values have multiple y values. Can this cause a problem?

Comment: What do you mean by your data has multiple *y* values? Does it mean each data point *x* has a feature of output values corresponding to different coordinates on your graph?

Comment: yes, for example in my data I have x=3,y=4 then x=3 y=5

Comment: Then the title of your question is slightly misleading, since you do not have multi-dimensional output (i.e. no y1 and y2 to predict from one x). As I stated in my answer, your question is too broad to give any certain answer. Most likely it is going to work out, since the network will learn something between the multiple values.

Answer (score 3):

Your model can have any number of hidden layers with any number of hidden units. However, in case you want to do multi-dimensional regression, the number of output units of your neural network model must have the same dimensionality of your desired output vector *y*. For instance, suppose your examples have three features as shown in the picture below (borrow from a Google search). You may have any number of hidden layers (here one) and in the last layer you have a vector of size two, corresponding to the number of dimensions your target *y* has.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**What will happen most likely**: Going with your example of (x=3,y=4) and (x=3,y=5), the neural network will most likely learn to predict a value between 4 and 5 when given the input (x=3). And I suppose this is what you want your regression to do. So, to answer your question: No, most likely there won't be any problem.

I suggest you try it and ask another question when you encounter a *specific* problem or large error for *specific* values.

Comment: @agold Left a comment and reformulated my answer. (Thanks to you I just learned that something like the Low Quality Post Queue exists)